# xgraph in Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: apt

Having issue in installing xgraph

Command used in (Ubuntu 18.4)

```
sudo apt-get install perl xgraph libxt-dev libx11-dev libxmu-dev
```

Issue : "E: Unable to locate package xgrapg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04, `xgraph` is not available in the repository. You might have to consider installing my manually downloading `.deb` packages.
Open up a terminal and paste the following commands one by one.

```
sudo apt install perl libxt-dev libx11-dev libxmu-dev
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xgraph/xgraph_12.1-17_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```